# Django and GWT integration

Tags: django, gwt

After reading all sorts of posts on the subject I'm still wondering what would be more convenient: using JSON or XML. what are the pros and what are the cons for each?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

### JSON

**Advantages**:

- small and compact --> best network footprint
- parsing is fast (faster than XML)

**Disadvantes**:

- references are difficult to implement
- (harder to read by humans)
- no schema

### XML

**Advantages**:

- (human readable?)
- schema for validation checks
- namespaces
- XQuery and XPath
- mature and used for a long time
- a lot of tools available.
- references are easier to implement

**Disadvantes**:

- more overhead than json
- parsing is slower

I personally would always use JSON for GWT apps because it is so lightweight easy to use.

You can also check out [Pirti](http://code.google.com/p/piriti/) which makes it really easy to convert from XML/JSON to DTOs and vice versa on the client side.